# calculating the population of destinations

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, population

I would like to calculate the population of my destinations I created with OD Cost Matrix. I have got population data but I don't know how to find the population of my destinations scattered on my population data. Can you help me, please?
[image]

Comment: What do the green dots and the blue squares grid represent? You have population data: In vector format? With which desagregation? Please describe the problem better.

Comment: Spatial join, perhaps?

Comment: Green dots represent destinations and blue squares are polygons with population data(shapefile feature class). Whole blue grid comprises of 746 polygons. I am trying to perform an accessibility analysis with od cost matrix and trying to calculate it in relation to the population of destinations.